# Проблема с PHP. Не обрабатывает форму

Tags: php, html, form

Не обрабатывает форму

```
`<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$sername=$_POST['sername'];
$famil=$_POST['famil'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$fakult=$_POST['fakult'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$verno=$_POST['verno'];
$nowdate=date("d.m.y - H:i:s");
$base="base.cvs";
$filform=strlen($name)*strlen($sername)*strlen($famil)*strlen($gender)
*strlen($fakult)*strlen($email)*strlen($verno);
$fillmail=strpos($email, "@uch.btu");
if($fillform<1)
print("Вы заполнили не все поля<br>вернитесь <a href='Anketa.htm'>назад</a><br>");
elseif($fillmail<1)
print("Не верный адрес электронной почты<br>вернитесь <a href='Anketa.htm'>назад</a><br>");
else 
{
$text=$name ."^^". $sername ."^^". $famil ."^^". $date ."^^". $gender ."^^". $fakult ."^^". 
$email . 
"^^". $nowdate ."\n";
$fp=fopen($base,"a");
fputs($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);
}
?>`
```

```html
Листинг 7.1. Файл anketa.htm
<html>
<head>
<title>Анкета</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align=center>Анкета студентов БТЭУ</h1>
<form action="executor.php" method="POST">
<table border="0">
<tr>
Сбор 
информации 
о студенте
Проверка полноты 
внесенных данных. 
Запись данных в файл
Вывод данных 
по всем студентам 
в виде таблицы
28
<td align=right>Имя</td>
<td ><input name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Отчество</td>
<td ><input name="sername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Фамилия</td>
<td ><input name="famil"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Дата</td>
<td ><input size="10" name="date"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Факультет:</td>
<td >
<select size="1" name="fakult">
<option>Учетно-финансовый</option>
<option>Экономики и управления</option>
<option>Коммерческий</option>
<option>Не знаю</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Пол:</td>
<td ><input name="gender" value="men" type="radio">Мужской<input name="gender" value="female" 
type="radio">Женский</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Номер группы:</td>
<td ><input size="4" name="group"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>Почтовый адрес:</td>
<td ><input size="25" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>подтверждение введенных данных</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=right>
<input value="Отправить" name="B1" type="submit">
</td>
<td ><input name="b2" value="Сброс" type="reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: У тебя кавычки перед кодом PHP. Если ты так отправил сюда - ничего страшного, но если у тебя это в коде - их следует убрать. Также посмотри на имя файла и обработчик, который висит на форме. Они должны быть одинаковы

Comment: @DarkSpace нет, кавычки только тут. Да и дело в том что код то работает, только не весь. он постоянно выдает, что не все поля заполнены